Trouble Connecting to Network Printer in PHP: Connection Timeout Issue (Error Code 110)
Question:
I'm encountering an issue when trying to connect to a network printer (BC-99AC) using PHP. Here's the error message I'm receiving:
Cannot initialise NetworkPrintConnector: IP: 192.168.123.100, Port: 9100, Error: Connection timed out, Error Code: 110 
I've verified that the printer is powered on and connected to the network correctly. Additionally, I've checked the IP address (192.168.123.100) and ensured that there are no firewall rules blocking the connection. I try to follow this github repository
Here's the relevant code snippet:
try {
    $connector = new Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\NetworkPrintConnector("192.168.123.100", 9100);
    $printer = new Mike42\Escpos\Printer($connector);
    // Other printing logic here...
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}


Despite these checks, I'm still experiencing the connection timeout issue. Can anyone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Are there any additional steps I should take or configurations I should check? Code Running on Hostinger server and its multi-branch restaurant application where I am trying to connect multiple devices within same network use single printer to print out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What did I try:
In attempting to connect to the network printer, I tried the following:

Verified that the printer is powered on and connected to the network.
Confirmed the IP address (192.168.123.100) and ensured it is correct.
Checked for any firewall rules blocking the connection.
Used the provided code snippet to establish the connection.
There is a web portal of printer provided my manufacturer, I print out from that portal successfully.
Also there is app in play store named ESC POS Wifi Print Service. Print also come out using that app.

What I expected was that the code would successfully connect to the network printer without encountering any errors. However, despite these checks, I still encountered a connection timeout issue with Error Code 110.
Any insights into why the connection is timing out and how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would first try to print from the UI or command line, assuming you're using Linux, but the same is true for Windows.

@KIKOSoftware this time code is hosted on hostinger server. I also verified that there is no port blocking from their side.

You have a printer in the local network of Hostinger? I doubt that. The printer is probably located in your own local network. Those two networks cannot communicate with each other, using local addresses. Remember, PHP runs on the server, not in your browser. Your browser only receives the output of what PHP generates on the server.

I've checked the IP address (192.168.123.100) and ensured that there are no firewall rules blocking the connection...you might want to check again, then. The 192.168.x.x address range is only for local LAN networks. That can never be a public IP. The hostinger server is (obviously) not in your local network. Therefore it cannot see your local LAN IP addresses. Presumably you have a NAT router which will a) present a single public IP to the outside world which is used as the source of any outbound connections from your LAN, and b) blocks all incoming connections by default.

If you really wanted the hostinger server to see your printer you'd have to enable port forwarding in your router and open the correct port and forward it to the printer's local IP address, and make hostinger use your public IP to connect. BUT I would strongly recommend that you don't do that because it opens up any number of security and other problems - how do you ensure only the PHP app connects to the printer and not world+dog? Can you be sure the printer doesn't have vulnerabilities which would expose your entire LAN to attacks? Is your public IP static / stable? etc etc.

Basically this is not a programming question or problem, it's an issue of system architecture and networking, and your apparently lack of understanding of the fundamentals of those subjects. If you run your PHP code from a webserver on the same LAN as the printer, you'll likely be able to connect correctly. But if you need to run the PHP app on a public internet-facing server, then you'll have to substantially rethink your approach to the printing requirements of the application.

@ADyson 192.168.123.100 is the static IP or printer and my router gateway is 192.168.123.1

@KIKOSoftware when i open printer portal on browser using the ip 192.168.123.100 and press button of test print then print comes out. The point is printer web portal is not in my local network, it is also on some server and printer coming. So maybe I am missing something that we have to figure out.

my router gateway is 192.168.123.1...sure but again that's another LAN address visible from the LAN side and is not public. Your router/gateway will have a separate public IP which it uses when connecting to the internet. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation if you don't understand the basic principles here.

when i open printer portal on browser using the ip 192.168.123.100 and press button of test print then print comes out. The point is printer web portal is not in my local network...not sure what you mean? 192.168.123.100 is definitely a local network address. Or do you mean you have a copy of the printer portal software on your local network and on a public server? Your description was unclear.

maybe I am missing something that we have to figure out...I'm pretty sure my previous comments have already explained what you had missed. Having read those (and maybe done some background research) is there anything specific you're still not sure about?

The "printer portal" you're talking about is probably printing directly from your browser, not from their server, and your browser is in your local network.

@ADyson not sure what you mean? 192.168.123.100 is definitely a local network address.... I want to say that the printer portal have some code in server, but now i am realizing that portal code should be in the IC that is installed within printer. but my code is in the server and i want to access printer that is in my local network.
ok, guide me properly please what I have to do more. I cannot buy static IP. Basically its restaurant software and when it will be open on tab then print should come out from network printer from button is pressed from tab. This is what I have to achieve

So make a LAN in the restaurant, and put a webserver (running PHP) and the printer all inside the same LAN. You might be able to do some clever stuff with cloud virtual networking to link a private LAN and internet-facing server if you host the webserver in one of the big public clouds, but that might be a bit advanced for you at the moment by the sounds of it.

P.S. I want to say that the printer portal have some code in server, but now i am realizing that portal code should be in the IC that is installed within printer...I can't tell if the "printer portal" you're referring to is some software you wrote, or something that was provided by the printer manufacturer (and whether you're trying to integrate it into your PHP code, or if that's a completely separate thing)? Again your descriptions are really vague and unclear, it is not helping us to assist you if you cannot explain the situation fully and clearly.

@ADyson printer portal is provided by the printer manufacturer

Ok. Well it is subject to the same constraints as your PHP code - to make a connection to the printer it must be installed in the same network as the printer.

@ADyson its a web application not a desktop application. What should I do? One think that I have in mind that tab redirect command to the local PC to which this printer is installed and configured with that static IP address. But how to do this I also not clear about it

I told you: make a LAN in the restaurant, and put a webserver (running PHP) and the printer all inside the same LAN. I'm assuming users do not need to access the application from outside the LAN, if they are wanting to print from there to a physical printer which is located in the restaurant. Or did I misunderstand something? Again you did not really make clear what the full scenario is.

@ADyson I cannot place php code to the local machine as we have multiple branches connected to the centralized database.

@ADyson is there any way to only place printer code to local, then let me know. Its laravel application

Where is the printer located then? Is there one printer in each branch? Or should everyone print to a single printer in an office somewhere?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
